# I get wrong output in ICU4J library

Tags: java, icu4j

I want to convert date from Persian calendar to Gregorian Calendar.
For this, I use ICU4J library (version 65.1). 
The problem is that this library gives wrong output for some dates.

Here is my code:

```
ULocale locale = new ULocale("fa_IR@calendar=persian");

GregorianCalendar gregoriancal = new GregorianCalendar();

Calendar persiancal = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
//            year month day
persiancal.set(1398, 11, 16);

gregoriancal.setTime(persiancal.getTime());

String day = gregoriancal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "";

System.out.println(day);
----------------------------------------
output: 6
```

this date in persian calendar ( 1398/11/16 ) equls to 2020-02-05 Wednesday February in Gregorian Calendar

but it gives me 6 as output ( while it should give 5 )

is there something wrong with my code that results in a wrong output??

Comment: Use a [GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) with the correct Iranian time zone. At time 00:00 such being one day off can easily happen.

Comment: @Joop Eggen, could you please write the code ? Thanks

Comment: @omid           i need your help. please give me your email address or wats app number

Comment: Sorry farhad, I am switching firms end of february, and there is relatively much to do. But I'll look into the code a second time.

Comment: Tried out zero based months as in java.util.Calendar. see my answer. It fits, but please do some research. I have no time.

Comment: Hi. Do you solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534443/noclassdeffounderror-com-ibm-icu-util-ulocale can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the javadoc passing the `ULocale` should do the trick to put the GregorianCalendar in the correct time zone:

```
com.ibm.icu.util.GregorianCalendar gregoriancal =
    new com.ibm.icu.util.GregorianCalendar(locale);
```

---

I think the month may be 0-based as in java.util.Calendar.

```
    persiancal.set(1398, 11-1, 16);
```